# Setting NumberOfItemsInSection of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a dictionary dataSource for my `UICollectionView` with string keys 

`var myDict: [String: [ExampleClass]]`.

For the `numberOfSections` function, it is based on the count of key/value pairs of the dictionary dataSource.

For `numberOfItemsInSection` function, it should be based on the count of values in the array correlated to its string key.

The issue I have however is the section parameter of the `numberOfItemsInSection` function is of type Int, and I cannot return the correct `numberOfItemsInSection` from the dataSource since the key is type of String.

Any thoughts on how I could possibly use the integer value to get the correct count of values in the dictionary with string keys?

Comment: Simply return ‘yourDictionary.keys.count’

Comment: @Derp yourDictionary.keys.count will return number of sections, but not number of items in section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider some design changes in your data structure if the dictionary is not ordered by keys. Dictionaries (and sets) are unordered collections in Swift (and in Objective-C). This is by design.

To answer the specific question,

- `dictionary.count` will give you number of sections in CollectionView.
- `Array(dictionary.values)[index].count` will give you number of items in section at the given `index`.